# Using frames in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Can anyone help me understand how to display the following pattern using a Progress 4gl frame:
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5.

I have tried like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE a AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE b AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DO
    a =1 TO 5 WITH FRAME f:
    DO
        b = 1 TO a WITH FRAME f:
        DISPLAY  a SPACE SKIP.
        PAUSE.
    END.
END.
```

/* while displaying the answer is overwritten, how do I display the answer side by side? */

Comment: The output is exactly what I would expect from the given program, what else did you expect?

Comment: The answer what I'm getting is 1 next line 2 nl 3nl 4  nl  5 . .I want side by side 2 two times 3 three times so on . .

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't name both frames `f`. (Just a wild guess from someone who doesn't know progress-4gl)

Answer (score 3):

If you were sending your output to a file you could do it like this:

```
define variable a as integer no-undo.
define variable b as integer no-undo.

output to "output.txt".
do a = 1 to 5:
  do b = 1 to a:
    put b.
  end.
  put skip.
end.

output close.
```

Using DISPLAY and FRAME is not like text files or printers.  When you create a frame and DISPLAY "A" in it you are defining a single position where the variable will be displayed.

Every time that you DISPLAY A the value will be placed in the same position.

You can make it a DOWN frame and move to a new line with each iteration of the outer loop but you will still only have one position per line.

```
define variable a as integer no-undo.
define variable b as integer no-undo.

do a = 1 to 5 with frame f:
  do b = 1 to a:
    display b with frame f.
  end.
  down with frame f.
end.
```

To have multiple positions you need multiple variables or an array or you can build a string (doydoy44's solution).  Here is an example with an array:

```
define variable a as integer no-undo.
define variable b as integer no-undo.
define variable c as integer no-undo extent 5 format ">>>>".

do a = 1 to 5 with frame f:
  do b = 1 to a:
    c[b] = b.
  end.
  display c with frame f.
  down with frame f.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sur to understand what is the problem.
May be this can help you:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE a AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE b AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE woutput AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
DO
    a =1 TO 5 WITH FRAME f:

    woutput = "".
    DO 
        b = 1 TO a WITH FRAME f:
        woutput = woutput + " " + string(b).
    END.
    DISPLAY TRIM(woutput) SKIP .
    PAUSE.
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are talking about is what I call a *down frame*.  ABL creates a frame automatically for any output, and if you are displaying a series of records from a table, it knows to make that frame a down frame, for example:

```
for each customer no-lock:
    display customer.
end.
```

But in your example you aren't using `for each`. To get the down frame behaviour you are going to have to make it happen yourself.

Here is the simplest code that will give you that:

```
def var v-i as int no-undo.

do v-i = 1 to 10 with down:
    display v-i.
    down.
end.
```

It's actually clearer what is going on, though, if you spell things out a bit further.  Let's define a named frame, make it a down frame, and then use it:

```
def var v-i as int no-undo.

def frame f-x 
        v-i
    with down.

do v-i = 1 to 10:
    display v-i with frame f-x.
    down with frame f-x. 
end.
```

It's almost always worth defining a frame if you are outputting something, I find.

Answer (score -1):

```
define variable a as int no-undo.                             
define variable b as int no-undo.                              
define variable res as char no-undo.  
               
update a.

b = 1.                  
repeat while(b <= a):

res = res + " " + string (b).               
   b = b + 1.                
   disp res format "x(20)".             
end.
```

Comment: From Review: Code-only answers are usually not welcome by the S.O. community. Would you please add some explanation text to it?